# Upgrade Linux Kernel 3.5.4 Manually

Tags: installation, kernel

Ok, so I'm not new to Linux, but by no means am I a guru, and its time for me to upgrade my Linux Kernel to 3.5.4 (I need new drivers only compatible with the newest kernel image), and I would like to do so manually.

What I mean is that I would like to download the official .tar.bz2 image from [here](http://www.kernel.org/), then extract the image, but after that how do I actually install the kernel image?

Comment: Did you consider to use binary pre-built packages instead? (As mentioned in the answer of @BuZZ-dEE) Or is there a reason for compiling/installing from upstream souce?

Comment: I did consider it, and at the time I dismissed it, as I though the kernel would do better if it was compiled on the platform it would run on. However after looking at these answers, and doing further research, it doesn't seem to matter, does it?

Comment: No, not really. Unless you do specific optimizations like settings specific compiler flags or manually configuring all the modules, it doesn't really matter performance wise. It is possible, however, to lower boot time a few seconds or so by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update your kernel to [v3.5.4](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/) by installing a [mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

> [**Do mainline kernel builds include Ubuntu specific drivers?**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds#Kernel.2BAC8-FAQ.2BAC8-DebuggingMainlineBuildsUbuntuDrivers.Do_mainline_kernel_builds_include_Ubuntu_specific_drivers.3F)
>
> By definition the mainline kernel builds are made from virgin unaltered mainline kernel sources and therefore do not, and should not, include any Ubuntu patches or drivers. There are also no binary drivers for these kernels.

Open a terminal and do the following:

```
mkdir v3.5.4-quantal
cd v3.5.4-quantal
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.4-030504_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_all.deb
```

**Only for 32 bit systems:**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-image-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_i386.deb
```

**Only for 64 bit systems:**

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-headers-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-image-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.5.4-quantal/linux-image-extra-3.5.4-030504-generic_3.5.4-030504.201209142010_amd64.deb
```

Install the kernel.:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: These packages are targeted for Quantal (12.10), not for 12.04. It could just work, but compatibility issues may arise now or later. I recommend installing the 3.5 kernel backported for Precise, for example via [Q-series LTS PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/q-lts-backport/+packages). For example, I have seen many compatibility issues installing 'plain' mainline kernels for Oneiric in Lucid (mainly GUI-related). Also, the question is about how to install (build) the kernel from source from kernel.org.

Comment: His question is not so clear, I think. Maybe he doesn't know that there are a binary mainline kernel for Ubuntu. You could install the quantal packages also in precise. If you only use open source drivers, it should work. I use those packages also with precise without problems.

Comment: @gertvdijk please explain me, why it should be necessary to backport a mainline kernel to a specific ubuntu version

Comment: Kernel configurations for compatibility with user-space, for example Xorg, filesystems, device management (udev/devfs), etc. Also packaging options that may be incompatible if some schemes are changed (new FHS for example). Backported kernels are usually being tested with older userspace, so that should improve user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling and installing upstream ('vanilla') kernels is described in this wiki article: [GitKernelBuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild). Should contain everything you need.