# Failed to enable MSI-X

Tags: kernel, msi

I tried to make a copy of my kernel so I can use the copy of the .config to mess around with it so I can learn it better. I followed the guide here - http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/

However, now when I boot into the kernel, it says "xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Failed to enable MSI-X". Everything appears to work fine, but I don't know what to do to fix that error.

Also, I tried to boot into the old kernel...and it gives me the error too. I thought I was making a copy of it, but apparently I changed it?

A friend told me that I should have used the Debian method on that guide and that the way I did it gave me an "unpackaged kernel" (I don't fully understand what that means). Is this true? And if so, how can I fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.0: Failed to enable MSI-X` means that MSI-X could not be enabled for your USB 3.0 controller (`xhci`). MSI is an enhanced way to handle interrupts, but if it doesn't work for a device, it may just work without it.

So, consider it as a warning. Workarounds to get rid if the error like adding `pci=nomsi` to your kernel will disable it completely and you don't want that for performance reasons.

Several options I think of:

- First, update your PC's BIOS if there's an update available. It might expose some wrong data in the DMI and therefore misleads the kernel in detecting such things.
- Discuss this on the kernel mailing list.
- File a bug against the driver (kernel module).
- Disable USB 3.0 in your BIOS if you don't need it.

Comment: Hmm, well I never got this error before I messed with the kernel...although I didn't change anything in it other than the name. Is there a way to download the latest kernel?

Comment: @Sterling Please limit your amount of questions to one. :) Anyway, try this: [answer to Upgrade Linux Kernel 3.5.4 Manually](http://askubuntu.com/questions/189454/upgrade-linux-kernel-3-5-4-manually/189458#189458)

Comment: Okay one last related question though - is this something that may be fixed in time by an update?

Comment: @Sterling Yes it may be fixed sooner or later. However, if it is caused by some misleading BIOS/DMI of your OEM, kernel maintainers may be reluctant to fix this in mainline, or, depending how popular your specific hardware is, it might got unnoticed completely and never gets fixed.