# no DVD since upgrade to kernel 3.7

Tags: kernel, dvd

My problem is the following, since an upgrade to Kernel 3.7, my cdrom/DVD drive has dissapeared.
There is no trace of /dev/sr0 /dev/cdrom0 and others.
The drive does not show up in dmesg.

I see many errors like prereset failed erro = -19 and AE0x300B.

I tried several things, like adding modprobe.blacklist=pata_acpi to grub : 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="modprobe.blacklist=pata_acpi"
I also tried upgrading to (I believe not supported) 3.7.1-030701-generic
and a downgrade to 3.5.4 (here my dvd shows up, but the network is not working).
As everything was working in 3.5, I would like to install 3.5.0.21-generic, but I can not find instructions / location how to do this.

Any suggestions ? (both are appreciated : going forward to solve my dvd drive problem or downgrade the kernel).

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not recommended to upgrade kernels unless you have a specific problem to solve. If you do not have problems with kernel 3.5 I suggest you stick with it.

Comment: Sorry, this is not helpfull, this update appeared in my list, probably after I added an apt to get the latest Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Then if the added ppa offered to install kernel 3.7 and you do not want to use it, but cannot uninstall it for some dependency issue, you may modify grub to boot from an "older" kernel. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/216420/27968).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you uninstall the 3.5.0.21 kernel? If you did not, uninstall the 3.7 and 3.5.4 kernels and you're done. To be sure you do have a working kernel in a terminal type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`.

If you did uninstall the 3.5 kernel, you can:

1. Disable the ppa which installed
   the 3.7 kernel by opening **Software Sources**. This has the
       consequence that the Nvidia packages won't get updated from the PPA.
2. In a terminal type: `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install linux-image`. Kernel 3.5 should be installed.
3. Reboot with the newly installed kernel.
4. Uninstall the 3.7 and 3.5.4 kernels and reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but this just installs vmlinuz-3.7.0-7-generic again. 
I did this yesterday from my resque USB (I tried uninstalling the 3.7 kernel as you also suggested, and ended up without kernel, so I had to use the USB installer).
To stay on a positive note, I am learning a lot now.

Comment: See modified answer.

Comment: I "solved" it by installing kernel 3.5.7 using this procedure : 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/189454/upgrade-linux-kernel-3-5-4-manually
One can find other kernels here : 
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ ,
just follow the same procedure for the kernel of your choice.

Then I deleted the newer kernels from my system, to avoid confusion.

The real issue : why do kernels 3.6 and 3.7 suddenly break a good working interface (I suspect the JMicron ATA/IDE interface) without warning ? This pc is from 2008.